# ansible inventory file location is it /etc/ansible/hosts or /etc/hosts?

Tags: continuous-integration, ansible, centos7, continuous-deployment

I am having one basic doubt on inventory file creation, whether the location of the inventory file name is

`/etc/ansible/hosts` or `/etc/hosts` ?

If both are same then why we need the inventory file settings differently?

Thanks,
Sathiyarajan M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The location of Ansible's default Inventory file is /etc/ansible/hosts. But you can override the inventory file location/path through the inventory directive in ansible.cfg.

The /etc/hosts is for an entirely different purpose, and I suggest that you read about it. Quoting from askubuntu, the purpose and format of /etc/hosts file

> Purpose
>
> The hosts file is one of several system facilities that assists in
>   addressing network nodes in a computer network. It is a common part of
>   an operating system's Internet Protocol (IP) implementation, and
>   serves the function of translating human-friendly hostnames into
>   numeric protocol addresses, called IP addresses, that identify and
>   locate a host in an IP network. In some operating systems, the hosts
>   file's content is used preferentially to other methods, such as the
>   Domain Name System (DNS), but many systems implement name service
>   switches (e.g., nsswitch.conf for Linux and Unix) to provide
>   customization. Unlike the DNS, the hosts file is under the direct
>   control of the local computer's administrator
>
> File content
>
> The hosts file contains lines of text consisting of an IP address in
>   the first text field followed by one or more host names. Each field is
>   separated by white space (blanks or tabulation characters). Comment
>   lines may be included; they are indicated by a hash character (#) in
>   the first position of such lines. Entirely blank lines in the file are
>   ignored. For example, a typical hosts file may contain the following:
>
> ## This is an example of the hosts file
>
> 127.0.0.1  localhost loopback ::1        localhost This example only contains entries for the loopback addresses of the system and their
>   host names, a typical default content of the hosts file. The example
>   illustrates that an IP address may have multiple host names, and that
>   a host name may be mapped to several IP addresses.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable information, its helped me alot.